# Complex Bootstrap stacked columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, stacked

I have a website, where the content is placed on 5 grid columns. On the "xs" it is trivial:

```
|   1   |
|   2   |
|   3   |
|   4   |
|   5   |
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8UjM.png

Question: How to make it look like this on "sm"?

```
|   1   ||              ||   2   |
|   4   ||       3      ||   5   |
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysH79.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the col-sm-offset-* class to arrange such a layout

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-8">2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">5</div>
</div>
```

Here is an example http://plnkr.co/edit/RITUeIfyMzngqGhT5211?p=preview

Comment: Result is not the same as in my image http://i.imgur.com/RjTqYxs.png - "3" column has to start from the top, actually I even cannot use 2 "row"s, but lets leave the the question simple...

Comment: I didn't notice the images.., here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/RITUeIfyMzngqGhT5211?p=preview

Comment: It is still not the same result: columns in mobile view should be 12345